# custom Bootstrap 3 nav-pills not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I custom `nav-pills` for change background in `default`,`hover` and `focus` Like this :

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:0;
    color: #777;
    border-right:5px solid #DDD;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    background:#f7f7f7;
    border-radius:0;
    color: #777;
    border-right:5px solid #005090;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

But in action `border-right` not true work and not show in 5 pixel. how do fix this ?

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/Sambora/2bvkd6f7/

problem:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's working to me, `border-right` is showing properly at 5px.

Comment: @nextstep: i see two border : `5px` and `1px`.

Comment: Nothing weird in the fiddle. You need to clarify what the problem is by stating clearly what you want to see vs what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Here is the problem description. You can see the corner edges were slant in active class.http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/2bvkd6f7/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try `.nav-pills > li` instead of `.nav-pills > li > a`. That may be what you're looking for.

```js
 $('#myTabs a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
   $(this).tab('show')
 });
```

```css
.book-list-cat .nav-pills > li > a {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #777;
  border-right: 5px solid #ddd;
}
.book-list-cat .nav-pills>li.active>a,
.book-list-cat .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover,
.book-list-cat .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #777;
  border-right: 5px solid #005090;
}
.book-list-cat .nav-pills > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-3 book-list-cat nopadding">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="myTabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">information </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9 book-details nopadding">
  <div class="tab-content book-details-block">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">information</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want the effects on hover too. You got the same commands for active, hover and focus. which is why you dont see the difference.

If i got you right, your css should be like this.

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    background:#FFF;
    border-radius:0;
    color: #777;
    border-right:5px solid #DDD;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-pills > li > a:hover {
   background:#f7f7f7;
    border-radius:0;
    color: #777;
    border-right:5px solid #005090;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-pills>li.active>a, .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover, .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus {
    background:#f7f7f7;
    border-radius:0;
    color: #777;
    border-right:5px solid #005090;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
```